# getting this TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react.js app to search and display GitHub users. I'm getting the above message when I try and display the users. Any tips on how I get around this?

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import UserItem from './UserItem';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import GithubContext from '../../context/github/githubContext';

const Users = () => {
  const githubContext = useContext(GithubContext);

  const { loading, users } = githubContext;

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {users.map(user => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const userStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)',
  gridGap: '1rem'
};

export default Users;
```

Comment: show your `GithubContext` file or make sure `users` is not empty (add another `if` statement)

Comment: `console.log(users)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional chaining for this purposes, in this case you will not have error, and when users become an array all users will be rendered.
e.g.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import UserItem from './UserItem';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import GithubContext from '../../context/github/githubContext';

const Users = () => {
  const githubContext = useContext(GithubContext);

  const { loading, users } = githubContext;

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {users?.map(user => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const userStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)',
  gridGap: '1rem'
};

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

The array hasn't been created by the time you call the map function - you can make the map function conditional on the array existing so it won't call unless it's ready.